# Some of my locals are not passed to my partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, partial-views, actionview

I encountered a very strange problem.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
<%= render partial: 'my_partial', locals: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } %>
```

And the partial

```
<%= a %>
<%= b %>
<%= c %>
```

Trying to run this gives me the following error

```
NameError - undefined local variable or method `a' for #<#<Class:0xb529d244>:0xb4f8c80c>:
```

If i remove `<%= a %>` and `<%= b %>` from my partial c gets outputted, without any problem.

Any help as to why this is happening, is much apreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In rails 3 use this syntax :

```
<%=  render "my_partial", :a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3 %>
```

**Edit:**
Instead Try this:

```
<%= render 'my_partial', :locals => {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3 } %>
```

Comment: The syntax doesn't matter. The result is identical. It turned out I was calling the partial from another location where I wasn't passing the locals..

Comment: Edited my answer check the edited one should work for you.Let me know.

Comment: The edited one won't work, but I already solved my answer. It turned out to be something else entirely. But it is either `render partial: 'partial', locals: {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}` or `render 'partial' a: 1, b: 2,  c: 3`